# Php filter select option

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a filter option using a select dropdown box and I don't know where I am failing. I have a search bar that works perfectly but I want to able to select the location where I would like to search .
For example I can type the name of the job I'm looking for but I would like to filter the locations to only view in one city 
Here is my code

Edit : Thanks to ADyson I made some edits to the code I will post the new code over the last one

```
        <?php
    require 'views/header.php';
    $connection = getDbConntection();

    // Search // 
    if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {

        $data = [
            'job_name' => '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%',
            'location_id' => $_GET['location_id']
        ];
        $searches = $connection->prepare("select jobs.id, jobs.name as job_name, salary as job_salary, description, location_id, domain_id , locations.name as location_name , domains.name as domain_name from jobs 
    LEFT JOIN locations ON jobs.location_id = locations.id
    LEFT JOIN domains on jobs.domain_id = domains.id "
                . "where jobs.name like :job_name"
                . 'AND location_id = :location_id');
        $searches->execute($data);
        $searches= $query->fetchAll();
    // List // 
    } else {
        $query = $connection->query("select jobs.id, jobs.name as job_name, salary as job_salary, description, location_id, domain_id , locations.name as location_name , domains.name as domain_name from jobs 
    LEFT JOIN locations ON jobs.location_id = locations.id
    LEFT JOIN domains on jobs.domain_id = domains.id ");
        $searches = $query->fetchAll();
    }
    ?>

    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
        <div class="w3-content">

            <h1 class="center"> Jobs table </h1>
            <br>
            <form style="text-align:center" action="index.php" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="search" value="Search jobs..." onfocus="this.value = ''" class="btn btn-danger">
                <select name="location_id"  class="btn btn-danger">
                    <?php foreach ($searches as $location): ?>
                        <?php $selectedText = ($location['id']) ?>
                        <option value= <?= $selectedText ?> > <?= $location['location_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-danger">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger">Back to list </a>
            </form>
            <br>

            <div  class="center">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th> Job Name</th>
                        <th> Job Location</th>
                        <th> Job Domain</th>
                        <th> Job Description</th>
                        <th> Job Salary</th>

                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($searches as $key => $job_name) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?= $job_name['id'] ?></th>
                            <th style="background-color: lightskyblue"><?= $job_name['job_name'] ?></th>
                            <td><?= $job_name['location_name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $job_name['domain_name'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $job_name['description'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $job_name['job_salary'] ?></td>
                            <td> <a  class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php?id=<?= $job_name['id'] ?>">&nbsp; &nbsp; Edit &nbsp;</a> 
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=<?= $job_name['id'] ?>">Delete</a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>  
            </div>

            <style>
                table td, table th {
                    padding: 15px;
                    text-align: center;

                }
                table th {
                    background:#3390FF;
                }
                table {
                    width: 100%;
                    border: 3px solid #ccc;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                }

                .ce

nter {
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                border: 3px solid red;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the messy code, I'm new to coding in general

Comment: It looks like `'location_id' => $_GET['search']` should be changed to `'location_id' => $_GET['location_id']`. Right now, you're using the "search" text as the location ID! Also you have a syntax error later - `AND location_id = ;location_id` needs the `;` changing to `:`.

Comment: P.S. these should have been fairly easily to spot if you did some simple debugging and ensure you've got error logging set up properly. Have you spent any time learning how to debug? It's almost as important a skill as the programming itself. http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP. There may still be other problem which are not immediately obvious from a quick read-through of the code.

Comment: Oh and `$searchText = $_GET['search'];` is redundant because you never use the $searchText variable after that line. It has no purpose. You can simply remove this line of code.

Comment: Thnaks for the help ,i noticed the syntax error and the logical error after posting the code here and changed it. After i run the code i get this

Comment: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\TemaCarantina\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TemaCarantina\index.php(17): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TemaCarantina\index.php on line 17error

Comment: What I'm guessing is the problem is the data variable, but i dont realy know what to change about it

Comment: Hm. Try with `$data = [
        ':job_name' => '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%',
        ':location_id' => $_GET['search']
    ];`

Comment: Nope..same issue..

Comment: you definitely changed `location_id = ;location_id'` to `location_id = :location_id'`??

Comment: Please don't put your code into the comments like that. It is not easy to read, for one thing. If you need to add more info, your question has an "edit" button which allows you to update the post. The button is at the bottom of your post just under the little blue "php" and "mysql" tags. Please us it. Then you can format the code to be easily readable. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will delete thse comments and put the code there

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Just try changing `. 'AND location_id = :location_id'` to `. ' AND location_id = :location_id'` (i.e. add a space before the AND). I think your query will end up being `where jobs.name like :job_nameAND location_id = :location_id` otherwise - and that could cause a misinterpretation, I suspect. I'm not sure why you used `.` to join those bits anyway, it's not necessary - the rest of your query is a multi-line string and it works fine.

Comment: I fixed it , thnaks I will post the awenser

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  ADysom I solved the problem , here is the correct code

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
$connection = getDbConntection();

$locations = $connection->query("select * from locations");

// Search // 
if (!empty($_GET['search'])) {

    $data = [
        'job_name' => '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%',
        'location_id' => $_GET['location_id']
    ];
    $query = $connection->prepare("select jobs.id, jobs.name as job_name, salary as job_salary, description, location_id, domain_id , locations.name as location_name , domains.name as domain_name from jobs 
LEFT JOIN locations ON jobs.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN domains on jobs.domain_id = domains.id "
            . "where jobs.name like :job_name "
            . "AND location_id = :location_id ");
    $query->execute($data);
    $query = $query->fetchAll();
//    print_r($_GET);
// List // 
} else {
    $query = $connection->query("select jobs.id, jobs.name as job_name, salary as job_salary, description, location_id, domain_id , locations.name as location_name , domains.name as domain_name from jobs 
LEFT JOIN locations ON jobs.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN domains on jobs.domain_id = domains.id ");
    $query = $query->fetchAll();
}
?>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
    <div class="w3-content">

        <h1 class="center"> Jobs table </h1>
        <br>
        <form style="text-align:center" action="index.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" placeholder='Search jobs..' name="search"  onfocus="this.value = ''" class="btn btn-danger">
            <select name="location_id"   class="btn btn-danger">
                <?php foreach ($locations as $location): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $location['id'] ?>">
                        <?= $location['name'] ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-danger">
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger">Back to list </a>
        </form>
        <br>

        <div  class="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th> Job Name</th>
                    <th> Job Location</th>
                    <th> Job Domain</th>
                    <th> Job Description</th>
                    <th> Job Salary</th>

                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($query as $key => $job_name) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?= $job_name['id'] ?></th>
                        <th style="background-color: lightskyblue"><?= $job_name['job_name'] ?></th>
                        <td><?= $job_name['location_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $job_name['domain_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $job_name['description'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $job_name['job_salary'] ?></td>
                        <td> <a  class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php?id=<?= $job_name['id'] ?>">&nbsp; &nbsp; Edit &nbsp;</a> 
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=<?= $job_name['id'] ?>">Delete</a> </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>  
        </div>

        <style>
            table td, table th {
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;

            }
            table th {
                background:#3390FF;
            }
            table {
                width: 100%;
                border: 3px solid #ccc;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            .center {
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                border: 3px solid red;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            ::placeholder { 
                color: white;
                opacity: 1; 
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW Small thing, but the query could still be made into all one string: `select jobs.id, jobs.name as job_name, salary as job_salary, description, location_id, domain_id , locations.name as location_name , domains.name as domain_name from jobs 
LEFT JOIN locations ON jobs.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN domains on jobs.domain_id = domains.id 
            where jobs.name like :job_name 
            AND location_id = :location_id"`. There' no need for the where clause to be separate strings.